# Using a final loop value on mid-loop numbers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I hope the title was even somewhat comprehensible.  I have a function that compares two values, one of which is an average of all the values of the first.

Basically, I want to find the distance between the Long, Lat of n number of markers and a central marker.  I have a loop that pushes my "results" variable to an array and, at the end of the loop, finds an average Lat, Long that creates a center point. The problem is that I want to find the distance between each of these "results" and the center point, but mid-loop, the average marker isn't finalized yet.

Harder to explain than to show; I have a demo set up here; to see what I mean, click the Update Button in the results pane: http://jsfiddle.net/Cory2711/m55Ef/. You'll see that 
the circle emanating from California is correct, since it's the last one made (with the full average point found). The circle coming from New York is made mid-loop, and thus has an incomplete average marker to measure to.

My Javascript (The issues are focused around the "markers" section:

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
var gMapAPIKey = 'AIzaSyBUlnM6c7LqCR79UM9mTKvSNK6V7gzKsmE';
var namearray = document.getElementsByName("name");
var form = document.getElementById("addressform");
var addBtn = document.getElementById("addperson");


//GOOGLE MAPS API SCRIPTS
var streetarray = document.getElementsByName("street");
var cityarray = document.getElementsByName("city");
var geocoder;
var map;
var results;
var mapArray = new Array();
var AvgLat = 0;
var AvgLng = 0;
var j;
var newLatLng;
var dynamicRadius;




function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    //centered on Carrollton, Texas -- Change lat,long values to change initial map area
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.999173, -96.897413)
}
//change Id reference to the div/container that contains the google map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
//Loop through and concate street and city values to find long,lat values for all fields
for (var cName = 0; cName < namearray.length; cName++) {
    var address = streetarray[cName].value + cityarray[cName].value;

    //start geocode copy  & paste text from API reference
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var results = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(results);
            console.log(results);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results,

            });
            //Push lng/lat locations to the mapArray and find AvgLat/Lngs
            mapArray.push(results);
            var j = mapArray.length;
            AvgLat = (AvgLat + results.lat());
            AvgLng = (AvgLng + results.lng());

            console.log(mapArray, AvgLat, AvgLng, j)

            //Begin Marker Scripts

            var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: results,
                radius: 15000,
                strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#0000FF",
                fillOpacity: 0.4


            })
            var centerLocation = {
                    lat: AvgLat / j,
                    lng: AvgLng / j,
                }

           var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerLocation.lat,     centerLocation.lng);
           var dynamicRadius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween     (results, newLatLng);
            if (j == namearray.length) {

            markerCircle.setRadius(dynamicRadius*1.15)                    
                map.setCenter(newLatLng);
                var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: newLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Center Marker",
                })
                var centerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: newLatLng,
                    radius: 15000,
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: 0.4,
                    map: map,
                })


            }
            markerCircle.setRadius(dynamicRadius*1.15)
            markerCircle.setMap(map);


        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });


}
}

//Initialize the first map on load -- When form is submitted geocode addresses and   places markers on the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
form.addEventListener("submit", codeAddress, false);
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", addPerson, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was that you're not limited to looping over your data only once. The data will still be there after you loop over it (unless you change or destroy it in the process).

So, you'd use two loops.

First loop calculates the center point.

Second loop calculates all of the distances from that point.

But as I look over your code I see there's a bit more to it than that.

Inside your main loop where you iterate over `namearray`, the loop calls `geocoder.geocode()` for each element of this array. Then inside the geocoder callback is where the work is done.

The interesting thing is that this code is not actually part of your main loop at all. It appears inside that loop, but it's called much later, as the geocode responses come back one by one.

So let's assume that there are no errors in the geocoding (bad assumption, but we'll run with it for a moment). Your geocoder callback already pushes each geocoding result onto `mapArray`. So what you could do is have this callback code *only* do this and not do any of the center/circle calculations. So your geocode call might look more like this:

```
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            mapArray.push({ latLng: results[0].geometry.location });
            AvgLat += results.lat();
            AvgLng += results.lng();
        } else {
            mapArray.push({ error: status });
            ++nErrors;
        }

        // Might want to update a progress indicator here
        // if the geocoding takes a while?

        if( mapArray.length == namearray.length ) {
            // Everything is geocoded, now get to work
            drawMap();
        }
    });
```

(`nErrors` should be defined above the loop where you initialize your other variables with `var nErrors = 0;`)

Then completely outside your current main loop, you add this function:

```
function drawMap() {
    if( nErrors ) {
        // complain about error
        return;
    }

    var center = {
        lat: AvgLat / j,
        lng: AvgLng / j,
    };
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng( center.lat, center.lng ) );

    for( var i = 0;  i < mapArray.length;  i++ ) {
        // Create marker and draw circle here
    }
}
```

So a couple of other points. First, calculating the average lat/lng this way doesn't sound quite right. I would give some thought (and testing) to cases where markers are different sides of the 0° and 180° meridians. You may be OK there, I just never count on it!

Also is the "average" lat/long actually what you want here? (It may be, just asking.) If you have many markers near each other and very few markers at some distance (e.g. 10 markers in CA and 1 in NY), the "average" will be very near to that cluster of markers. That may be what you want, but if not, there are other ways to calculate various kinds of "centers".

For example, one common way is to create an empty `LatLngBounds` object, and then extend those boundaries with each position you receive. So up at the top with your other variable initialization you'd add:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
```

And then inside each successful geocode callback you'd replace this:

```
            AvgLat += results.lat();
            AvgLng += results.lng();
```

with:

```
            bounds.extend( results );
```

Then in `drawMap()` you'd replace this:

```
    var center = {
        lat: AvgLat / j,
        lng: AvgLng / j,
    };
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng( center.lat, center.lng ) );
```

with:

```
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
    var center = bounds.getCenter();
```

and use `center.lat()` and `center.lng()` if you need those individual values - but in the places where you have `newLatLng` you can now just use `center` directly because it *is* a `LatLng` object.

Even if you do want to use an "average" of the points for your circle calculations, you may want to use this bounding box approach for the map centering instead of centering the map on the calculated average.

One last thing is to watch out for rate limits and throttling on the geocoding. Maybe you're OK for a small number of markers, but it's possible that you may need to make the geocode calls with a time interval between them instead of firing them all of in a hard loop.

Comment: Quick question that's related: If I have two loops following one another, would the second loop wait for the first one to finish looping, or would it do the first loop of the first and then the first loop of the second? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When you mentioned using two loops, I saw a different way of organizing my code.  I'm rather new to coding, so my codes' efficiency is usually lacking some, so I appreciate the help. I didn't notice how much unnecessary repetition I was doing with my initial loop. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad to help. I added a few more thoughts on more general map and Maps API issues, feel to ping with any follow-up questions.

Comment: So the main point of this would be to determine the a location with the least amount of total travel for a number of people to meet.  If there's 10 people in Dallas, and one in California, it would make most sense for the person in California to come to the Dallas area instead of 10 people going half way, so that's intended.  The 0 and 180 degree problem you're talking about is known; I theory crafted that problem a few weeks ago, but since this would be aimed at people within a fairly short distance, and in the States, this shouldn't be an issue.  I will substitute the equation later.

Comment: Also, I don't imagine more than 20 points (at the most); I imagine most users would only want to find a location central to 5-10 people, if that. Throttling and rate limit issues will depend on the use it sees. Right now I have the application capped at 10 markers, which I don't think will cause issues.